# What happens if the credit card expires which is saved in Google Playstore?

Tags: google-play

I have a Google PlayStore account, now the credit card saved in the PlayStore account has expired last month. I received an email stating the billing account has terminated.

I have one app published from that Playstore account but it doesn't involve in any mode of billing.

Now, what am I supposed to do? Leave it as it is or do I need to add another credit card? Can a PlayStore account operate properly without any credit card saved in it?

Comment: Anyone any idea?